# How can I check whether parameter of function is nil or not?

Tags: objective-c

I made Sender class and sender object:

```
Sender *sender = [[Sender alloc] init];
```

Then, I wrote test:

```
// should success
[sender upload:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test2.jpg"] withName:@"test2.jpg"];
// should fail
[sender upload:nil withName:@"test2.jpg"];
```

Then, I wrote nil check code:

```
- (void)upload:(UIImage *)image withName:(NSString *)name
{
    if ([image isEqual:nil]) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But nil check is ignored. 
How can I check whether the image parameter is nil or not?
Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, replace `[image isEqual:nil]` with `image == nil`.

Long answer, when you write:

```
[image isEqual:nil]
```

you are asking for the message `isEqual:` to be sent to the object whose reference is stored in the variable `image`.

However you don't wish to send a message to an object, you wish to determine whether the variable `image` contains a reference to an object or not. To do this you need to compare the *value* of your reference with the "no reference" value - which is written `nil`. The value comparison operator in Objective-C (and C et al) is `==` so you need to test:

```
image == nil
```

Now you might ask why did the code you have execute without error, just not producing the result you expected, given that there is no object to send a message to? Objective-C supports sending messages to "no object", aka `nil`, and returns the "zero" value for the result type, i.e. `0`, `nil` etc. When converted to a boolean value, as in your `if` statement, a "zero" value produces `NO`.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if(!image)
```

or

```
if(image == nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

@yeesterbunny's answer is on point as to what you should do in this situation, but it's also good to know why.

Remember that every objc method call is a message. When you call

```
[objA isEqual:objB]
```

you're sending a message to objA asking whether it considers itself "equal" to objB.

If the "image" parameter to your method is nil, there's nothing there to send a message to. By definition, any message to nil returns nil. (And "nil" is the same as zero in an if statement.)

Moral of the story: test pointer equality with == (or !=, or implicitly as in "if (!image)") if you're looking for nil. Use isEqual: only when you want to test whether two objects (known to exist and of similar type) are semantically equal (e.g. when you want to know if two instances of NSString contain the same text).